# How to handle variables in a math expression parser

Tags: java, parsing

I finally managed to write a parser that can evaluate strings such as `sin(x)+x`. My lexer consider identifiers as variables. So for `sin(y)-x+c` I have three tokens with type `VAR`. I tried HashMap to put a double value for each variable string (i.e. "y", "x" and "c") and use these values in evaluation. But this way is slow. I am looking for a faster way for accessing and updating these variables. Is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: One way is to store the actual variable values in an indexed structure, an array, say - and then store just the index into this array in the hash map (with the variable name as key, obviously). That way, you can retrieve the variable's index once from the hash map (this lookup is probably what slows you down) and cache it locally in your tree token.

Comment: @internalservererror, thanks. I suppose your method works for retrieving values but not for updating values.

Comment: Why not? `LookupValue = IndexedStore[Index]; IndexedStore[Index] = SetValue;`